# Ensembles at home - how to do it?

Tags: homerecording, ensemble

I have seen two quite different examples of ensembles from home recently.

Sadly, the obvious solution of a web conference is unlikely to work as even good internet connections will probably have too much lag and feedback could be an issue.

One is [Gareth Malone's Choir at Home](https://www.classicfm.com/artists/gareth-malone/choirmaster-gareth-malone-home-chorus-coronavirus/).  I have been following this and the procedure is explained.  You download a guide track and listen to it on headphones while singing and recording yourself.  Later, the recordings will be assembled.  We have not heard the result yet.

Here is a rather different example: [The Rotterdam Philharmonic at home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eXT60rbBVk&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR3_SREIQ1M7M2UsjfOwse7t8zsugKGj6m_AWvRjEuV9EJzapzOHrEC6aqM).  This time the procedure is not explained.

How might it be done?  I am not asking how the Rotterdam Philharmonic did it specifically but just how this could be done, especially techniques that relative amateurs could use.

I guess that each player could listen to the same recording of the piece and play along with it.  The need for someone with the skills to collect the results and mix them seems unavoidable.

Comment: I know I've seen at least one or two recent questions about this, but can't find them in searching now. One easy method is to use a traditional (real) phone call, the latency is usually low enough that people can stay in time.

Comment: I can see that for a duo but it may be trickier with larger groups.  I guess that good players may be able to stay in time.

Comment: Creation of the isolation tag is not really relevant - this all comes under standard practices of working and recording individual tracks whilst apart. Good question though!

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Another name may be better, maybe remote collaboration, but it seemed useful to me to be able to distinguish this topic.  It adds complications beyond normal collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You can have everyone choose a specific metronome tempo such as 120 BPM and have everyone follow that exactly. Then with some editing, you can line up the audio and video recordings to create something like this:

Hope that helps